# Replacing List /Numpy array in the console output (Python)

Tags: python, list, numpy, printing

i want to implement a q-learning algorithm in a 2D Gridworld.

```
e.g.:
[[_,_,_,G],
 [_,O,_,P],
 [x,_,_,_]]
```

where "_" = Free Space,
"G" = Goal state, "P" = Pitfall, "O" = Obstacle, "x" = the agent that wants to get to the goal state

my code works so far but i have problems visualizing the way "x" walks.

At the moment i'm just printing the whole list again and again but i would rather have the old gridworld be replaced in the console by the new one so it looks like the agent is moving.
I tried to use \r but it didn't worked for lists /numpy arrays.

short version:
I want to print a list / numpy array over and over again, but the old one should be replaced in the console.

I hope someone can help me :D Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the list you want to print 1-dimensional?

Comment: no it's acutally 2-dimensional...i used this as a datastructure to acces the elements with "my_list[row_number][column_number]"

Comment: You want to animate?  The answer is likely to be dependent on your console.  I would solve that problem using: https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit

Comment: yes i want to animate it. My thought was just replacing the console output.
i automatically get an updated list and if i would be able to replace the list in the console with the new list, it should look like an animation